# How to shift all columns through a loop in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, shift

I'm new to Python and Pandas and I hope that someone can help me. I have the following Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': {0: Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-06-01 01:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-06-01 02:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-06-01 03:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-06-01 04:00:00')},
 'column_0': {0: 384.0,
  1: 389.0,
  2: 352.0,
  3: 352.0,
  4: 356.0},
 'column_1': {0: 386.0,
  1: 352.0,
  2: 352.0,
  3: 356.0,
  4: 375.0},
 'column_2': {0: 352.0,
  1: 352.0,
  2: 356.0,
  3: 375.0,
  4: 365.0},
 'column_3': {0: 350.0,
  1: 356.0,
  2: 375.0,
  3: 365.0,
  4: 358.0},
 'column_4': {0: 359.0,
  1: 375.0,
  2: 365.0,
  3: 358.0,
  4: 347.0})
```

```
            timestamp  column_0  column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0 2021-06-01 00:00:00     384.0     386.0     352.0     350.0     359.0
1 2021-06-01 01:00:00     389.0     352.0     352.0     356.0     375.0
2 2021-06-01 02:00:00     352.0     352.0     356.0     375.0     365.0
3 2021-06-01 03:00:00     352.0     356.0     375.0     365.0     358.0
4 2021-06-01 04:00:00     356.0     375.0     365.0     358.0     347.0
```

What I want to do is to shift the numbers in **column_1** down one row, in **column_2** down two rows, in **column_3** down 3 rows and so on.

I know that this can be done with the code

```
df['column_1'].shift(+1)
df['column_2'].shift(+2)
...
```

The manual method is too troublesome since there are actually over 40 such columns in total. That's why I would like to add a loop, so that the code doesn't get too long.
In the end the dataframe should look like this:

```
            timestamp  column_0  column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0 2021-06-01 00:00:00     384.0     NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 2021-06-01 01:00:00     389.0     386.0     NaN       NaN       NaN
2 2021-06-01 02:00:00     352.0     352.0     352.0     NaN       NaN
3 2021-06-01 03:00:00     352.0     352.0     352.0     350.0     NaN  
4 2021-06-01 04:00:00     356.0     356.0     356.0     356.0     359.0
...
```

Does someone have an idea how to do that? I'm not really skilled in programming and my attempts so far have failed. I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the ordered sequence of column names using `df.columns`.  From there it is quick to iterate over them and shift the column with the help of `enumerate`.  Since your first column is your timestamp, set the enumerate start value to -1 to align the column shift.

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns, -1):
    if i > 0:
        df[col] = df[col].shift(i)
```